# How to convert internal boot SSD from HFS+ to APFS?

Tags: ssd, apfs

**Many** web pages claim that when you install 10.13 on an SSD, you have an option to convert to APFS.  Many others claim that when you install 10.13 on an SSD, you will be converted to APFS whether you want it or not.

Neither was the case for me.  I have an internal SSD that upgraded to 10.13 and continued to the current 10.13.6.  Default disk utility knows it is SSD and HFS+ but will not convert it.  Recovery partition won't convert it either.  And in none of my upgrades was I ever offered the choice.

I don't want to erase and do a multi-hour install, then have to do a multi-hour restore from backup.  Especially since I recently did (10.13.6) from recovery partition and it did not convert.

One page said you can't do it on your boot volume till 2017.  But 2017 is long gone.

SSD was in this refurb when I bought it from the Boston Apple store January 2017.  I used Migration to put apps and accounts on it, Software Update since then.  Never used FileVault nor RAID nor Bootcamp.

UPDATE: As detailed in the question and the "half-answer," there was never an automatic update nor an offer to do so nor were any of my attempts to get around it successful as of August 2018.  I gave up on the idea at that point.  However, I noticed in disk utility today (13 Aug 2019) that my boot SSD is now APFS.  I have no idea when Apple did the conversion without asking, but it was after the updates to 10.13.0 through 10.13.6.  Now I have 10.14.6

Configuration info (when the question was asked—before the surprise conversion):

```
MBP-WWG:Desktop Admin$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage ISSD                    1.0 TB     disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS ISSD                   +1.0 TB     disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 1687664E-6E25-4DBD-9293-A6B0E4D90B0A
                                 Unencrypted

MBP-WWG:Desktop Admin$
```

[image: About]
[image: Finder]
[image: Drive]
[image: Volume]

Comment: I've never been given the option; it just did it without asking, twice. Once even after I'd manually converted it back to HFS. This was with an old Mac Pro 5,1 & an aftermarket SSD.

Comment: Can you share more about your disk setup? (screenshots from DiskUtility for example) ... Are you using RAID? CoreStorage? FileVault 1/2? etc

Comment: Try running “diskutil cs list” In terminal, and attach a screenshot of the result

Comment: @Harcker better copy and paste the text output of the command (as the OP did)  rather than a screen shot

Comment: @Harcker: It just says HFS, like everything else I already posted.

Comment: Amazing really - to see how differently this works for different users! I've upgraded two machines now, and was offered APFS as an option both times. Both machines had SSD drives; one (2011 17") with an aftermarket SSD, the other a 2016 with a "factory" SSD; no choice on that any longer  :(

Comment: No choice, right.  I find it extremely irritating that I had to buy a 2012 just because the newer models in the store had smaller RAM and SSD and neither could be increased without replacing the entire logic board.  I didn't have time to wait for something else to be shipped in.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have the ***beginning*** of an answer:

```
MBP-WWG:~ Admin$ apropos apfs
APFSUserAgent(8)         - APFS new container observer
apfs.util(8)             - APFS file system utility
apfs_hfs_convert(8) !!!! - convert an existing HFS file system to APFS file system
fsck_apfs(8)             - APFS consistency check
mount_apfs(8)            - mount an APFS volume
newfs_apfs(8)            - construct a new APFS volume
MBP-WWG:~ Admin$ man 8 apfs_hfs_convert
```

But the challenge is when the Terminal is open in recovery mode, how many environment variables do I have to set to make it actually work?  I know it comes up with `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` but none of those directories exist in recovery mode (they're all on the main volume).  I don't know whether redefining PATH is sufficient.  Some commands may need other environment variables to function.  (shared libraries, manpath,

Tempted to try it on the old machine that has a spinner instead of an SSD.

Comment: What if you install High Sierra on an empty external volume, boot from that, launch Disk Utility, click the eject button next to your internal boot volume's icon, select your internal boot volume's grayed out icon and choose Convert to APFS from the Edit menu?

Comment: Don’t have one big enough.  I did, however, create a bootable installer.  When that is booted, the convert executable on the internal drive can be invoked—and says “device busy”. And of course, if unmounted, “no such path.”  Next experiment: copy the executable into the installer before booting it:  (Afterward, “read-only filesystem”)

Comment: Try unmounting it then using Terminal to remount it non-read-only (/sbin/mount -uw /). Then unmount and try.

Comment: Can’t unmount the volume you booted from.

Comment: Assuming you're still booted from the bootable installer.

Comment: That’s the unreadable file system.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible from recovery mode and/or usb setup. Start the mac in recovery mode (hold cmd+R at boot). Open disk utility, select volume from the left click Edit and convert to APFS. If option is greyed out unmount the volume first from the toolbar.

Comment: Since it has already been converted by one of the many updates since asked, I can’t test this now.  However, in the original question, I clearly stated that the recovery partition will NOT do it.